# How not to lose data when moving a bitmap through activities using FileOutputStream (Android - java)?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, fileoutputstream

I am currently doing a steganography app using java and android, and i cant find a proper way of moving large bitmaps through activities without losing the hidden message in the image. Why is the bitmap changing when moving it through activities?

First activity:

```
String filename = "bitmap";
FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,stream);
stream.close();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, save_image.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity, the bitmap is received:

```
try {
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.openFileInput("bitmap"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: First, perhaps there should be only one activity, instead of two. Modern Android development calls for fewer activities, perhaps only one for the whole app, using fragments to manage screens. Second, even if you feel that you want multiple activities, you would not need to save a bitmap to disk just to start another activity. Carefully use a singleton repository object to cache the bitmap, letting go of it as soon as you are done.

Comment: Third, if your steganography is not surviving being written to disk, that is likely to be a bigger problem than just this specific scenario. Use Device File Explorer in Android Studio to copy the PNG to your development machine and see if your encoded message is contained in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... i will try to reduce the number of activities and see whats up with the png file. @CommonsWare